# jQuery with changing DIV

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
$('.expand-1').click(function(){
   $('.content-1').slideToggle('slow');
   $('.expanded-1').toggleClass('expanded-4');  
});

$('.expand-2').click(function(){
   $('.content-2').slideToggle('slow');
   $('.expanded-2').toggleClass('expanded-5');      
});

$('.expand-3').click(function(){
   $('.content-3').slideToggle('slow');
   $('.expanded-3').toggleClass('expanded-6');      
});
```

Basically when you click the box it Expands the box, however when I click the next box, the rest still stay open, what I am looking for is a way that when (Box1) is click that if Box2 or Box3 is still open they will close and only open Box1, if Box2 is click then Box1 and Box3 would stay Closed , and so on.

There is only going to be 3 Boxes on this page.

Comment: Post some markup please, if possible, set up an example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: search for `this` usage as well :)

Comment: Please paste your html code

Comment: if you're trying to make an accordion, you could look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/476Nq/

This might help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like,

```
$('.expand-1').click(function(){
   $('.content-1').slideDown('slow');
   $('.content-2,.content-3').slideUp('fast');
   $('.expanded-1').toggleClass('expanded-4');  
});

$('.expand-2').click(function(){
   $('.content-2').slideDown('slow');
   $('.content-1,.content-3').slideUp('fast');
   $('.expanded-2').toggleClass('expanded-5');  
});

......
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try this one:

```
$('[class^="expand"]').on('click', function () {
   var klicked = this.className.slice(-1);
   var num = Math.floor(klicked)+3;
   $('[class^="content-"]').hide();
   $('[class^="content-'+klicked+'"]').slideToggle('slow');
   $(this).toggleClass('expanded'+num);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a generic class to your boxes, say `box`, and then do the following,

```
$(".box").click(function(){
    $(".box").hide();
    $(this).slideDown('slow');

    //Do something else with the element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class .content to all your content and

```
$('.expand-1').click(function(){
    $('.content').not($('.content-1')).slideUp('slow'); // Close all open content except 1 
    $('.content-1').slideToggle('slow');
    $('.expanded-1').toggleClass('expanded-4'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is close all box, and then open the box you wish. Better if you use a class for all your boxes to expand/close the boxes.

Your HTML should looks like:

```
<div class="open">
  content 1
</div>
<div class="open">
  content 2
</div>
<div class="open">
  content 3
</div>
```

Where open will be the trigger class.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   $('.open').click(function() {
       $('.open').fadeOut('slow');
       $(this).fadeIn('slow');
   });
})
```